# How to get vim to autocomplete WordPress API functions?

Tags: plugin-development, ide

I guess built-in omnicomplete is a start, but perhaps we're talking some neocomplcache plugin module or something themsuch? Googling "vim wordpress autocomplete" doesn't really give much.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`tbex.xml` file from the IIS branch](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/iis/tbex.xml), and convert the `CodeCompletion` node to a Vim dictionary. This dictionary could be [used for auto-completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip91).

I haven’t tested it, but if you succeed make it public, that would be awesome. :)

Comment: I managed to get this working with [WordPress.vim](http://github.com/dsawardekar/wordpress.vim), by populating phpcomplete's completion dictionary from PHPUnit.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar Looks fantastic!

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar I think you should write a new answer to this question pointing to wordpress.vim - it certainly qualifies as a solution!